# bad urls from other site ?fb_xd_fragment= redirect

Tags: apache, url, redirect

I have in my log some URLS like:

http://www.mysite.com/mypage/?fb_xd_fragment=

I want to redirect this URL to

http://www.mysite.com/mypage

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_xd_fragment=
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1? [R=301]
```

Comment: If you implement this you're breaking any facebook widget functionality for users of iE 7-

Comment: Interesting, I never used IE7 so I wasn't aware of that. (I didn't know IE7 was still alive)